# Upper bound on smallest power of radical contained in the ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

Suppose $J \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is an ideal, and $I = \sqrt{J}$ is its radical. How large can the smallest integer $e$ for which $I^e \subseteq J$ be, specifically in terms of the maximal degree(s) of the Groebner basis of $J$ and $I$, and the number of variables $n$?

Is anything known in this regard?

I believe we can assume that $I$ is prime, and thus $J$ is primary. That is, knowing some upper bound that holds for all primary ideals $J$ would also give a bound for the general case.

So, maybe this could be seen as an analogue of "multiplicity of a root" for multivariates.

EDIT on 21-03-2024: Clarified that I want an upper bound in terms of degrees of Groebner bases and the number of variables. Also added why the primary ideal case could be sufficient.

Comment: Here is a silly comment: $(x_1^n)$ shows that this is arbitrarily large.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But even in this case, it grows linearly in the (maximal) degree of the Groebner basis, which is n. Do you happen to know an example where this dependence is say, super-linear in the degree of the Groebner basis?

Comment: @HankScorpio do you know any such upper bound or an ideal that achieves this super-linear dependence? Or did you mean to sugest that the question was incomplete, or is missing something simple? It'll be helpful if you could share.

Comment: The way this was originally written, there was a silly answer, and I gave it. You improved the post and specified you weren't looking for the silly answer and now I don't have anything insightful to say. I don't really know why you're trying to read so much in to a comment which begins "[h]ere is a silly comment", but good luck anyways!

Comment: I'm sorry if it felt like I was interrogating you. I just really want to know if anything like this is known. Also, I had missed the fact that you were sugesting the question should be improved (because otherwise it has a silly answer). So given your experience on the platform, I wanted to know if that's what you meant. Thanks, and good luck to you too.